# In Azure Bot Framework's WaterfallDialog, how do we go to a specific step?

Tags: c#, botframework

In my Azure Bot, I have a `GetWeather` Dialog with `WaterfallDialog`.
It has 4 steps in `WaterfallDialog`.

```
CheckExistLocationStepAsync,
AskLocationAsync,
ConfirmLocationAsync,
ReturnWeatherAsync
```

I know we can go next step by `stepContext.NextAsync`, or end the dialog with  `stepContext.EndDialogAsync`.

But, if I want to jump To `ReturnWeatherAsync` step from `CheckExistLocationStepAsync` step, how can I do it?

Thanks.

Can't find anything about jumping waterfall step in documentation.

Comment: Currently using this way:

`stepContext.ActiveDialog.State["stepIndex"] = 2;`

Not sure if it is the correct way.

Comment: That is a perfectly valid way.